# Munin: do not notify state changes to OK

Tags: munin

Munin-limits seems to trigger notifications for any state change (OK->CRITICAL, OK->WARNING, WARNING->CRITICAL) bidirectionally. Is there a way to prevent Munin from notifying returns to "OK"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I freely concede this question is about munin rather than NAGIOS.  However, the two tools live hand-in-glove, and NAGIOS's notification engine is sophisticated and configurable, whilst munin's isn't.  So instead of asking munin to notify you, have it inform NAGIOS and let NAGIOS do the notifying.  Then you can set restrictions on time of day, use service escalations to notify management if problems persist, craft the form of the notification so as to be more appropriate to the medium (SMS and email notifications shouldn't look like each other), and, yes, control whether notification is sent on recovery.

In the contact template, or wherever this is defined for you, change

```
service_notification_options    w,u,c,r,f,s
host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s
```

to eg

```
service_notification_options    w,u,c,f,s 
host_notification_options       d,u,f,s
```

That is to say, remove the `r` for recovery from both service and host notification options.  Or you can override this on a contact-by-contact basis, in the contact's definition.

I must apologise to the author of this question because I am so habituated to having munin notify via NAGIOS - all my munin installations, and there are quite a few of them, do that - that I didn't originally notice that the question was munin-specific.  However, my answer stands: if you want a notification engine that you can make configuration changes to, *use a configurable engine*.

Comment: thank you for your useful and correct answer which has solved my problem. As usual, the Thought Police at serverfault has downvoted my question. I will not delete though, since I am quite convinced that it will be helpful to others as well.

Comment: I spoke too soon. The advice to change 'service_notification_options' seems to relate to Nagios. The question, however, is how to change the behavior of Munin notifications (direct, not via Nagios).

Comment: aag, see my added comments above, and please accept my apologies!  As for the downvote, mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.